# Explicit way to define fonts in the document

Tags: beamer, fonts, beamerposter

I have been trying to set up a poster using `beamer`. My problem is that the poster has very clear specifications: 24-point for paragraphs, 24-point for figure captions, 28-point for authors' names and 36-point for title.

This might be for my lack of knowledge (even though I have been using LaTeX for about 6 years), but I feel like this is one way that word is way better than LaTeX (and it pains me to say that), since with word I know exactly which font is used each part.

In latex not only I can *only* choose some pre-defined fonts for my document in `\documentclass`, but after I do that it's not explicit which fonts are what size. (Is the base font the font for the paragraph? Then what font is the title? And the Section headers?)

Beamer tries to solve this with the `\setbeamerfont` command, but I found that for some reason it doesn't work for every theme, so either it really doesn't work, or I'm using it wrong and it's a counter-intuitive command.

My question is: is there a way to define each font in your document explicitly, easily, and that works across classes? (So I don't have to learn a command for `beamer`, a command for reports, etc.)

Here's a MWE. In this example some definitions work and some don't. But most importantly I can't use these definitions with other classes, so they're not general.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

% These work
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
% These don't work
\setbeamerfont{normaltext}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{30}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}

\title{Fake title for MWE} % Poster title
\author{Author 1 and Author 2} % Author(s)

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Summary}
We introduce a package that makes data processing
significatly more efficient:
\begin{itemize}
\item Easy to use
\item Oopen-source
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, but compilable example (MWE).

Comment: It's a general question. I don't see which MWE I could post to illustrate it better. I'll try to come up with something

Comment: You could post a MWE for a beamerposter pointing out where you want which size of text to be applied.

Comment: @TeXnician I added some MWE. Hope that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Do you really need to use beamer? Are you willing to switch to LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @RobtAll I have never tried LuaTeX. If it's better I see no reason not to change.

Comment: It seems that you don't need to switch to LuaLaTeX. Only reason to do that (if you already have a way of doing things) is to take advantage of the `fontspec` package. Based on the answer(s) provided, it seems that your problem can be solved without changing the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

To answer for the `% These don't work` fonts:

- `\setbeamerfont{normaltext}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{30}{32}}}`

  There is a missing space, it should be `normal text` and a little trick is necessary to use this template, namely `\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}`
- `\setbeamerfont{block body}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}` 
  This command already works perfectly fine, but you are not using `block` but `alertblock`, so you'll need `\setbeamerfont{block body alerted}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}`

---

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

% These work
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{block body alerted}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{36}{32}}}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{30}{32}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}

\title{Fake title for MWE} % Poster title
\author{Author 1 and Author 2} % Author(s)

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
text

\begin{alertblock}{Summary}
We introduce a package that makes data processing
significatly more efficient:
\begin{itemize}
\item Easy to use
\item Oopen-source
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]